# How do you transform a queries rows and columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not sure of the correct terminology but what I'm trying to do is to transform a MS Access query so that the rows and columns are swapped.

I'm trying to build a simple comparison query.

To start with I have a table which is selected with the following query:

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
|cnPart |qty    |desc       |mnPart |matl   |spec      |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|00001  |10     |blWidget   |w1000  |s1     |a4b7c3d4  |
|00002  |20     |brWidget   |w1001  |s1     |a4b7c3d4  |
|00003  |15     |gnWidget   |w1002  |s1     |a4b7c3d4  |
|00004  |5      |rdWidget   |w1003  |s1     |a4b7c3d4  |
|00005  |30     |vtWidget   |w1004  |s1     |a4b7c3d4  |
|------------------------------------------------------|

SELECT [cnPart],[qty],[desc],[mnPart],[matl],[spec] FROM PartData WHERE ([mnPart] IN ('w1000','w1001','w1002','w1003','w1004'))
```

In order to make it more easily presentable, I want to swap the rows and columns so that the end result is like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|cnPart |00001      |00002      |00003      |00004      |00005      |
|qty    |10         |20         |15         |5          |30         |
|desc   |blWidget   |brWidget   |gnWidget   |rdWidget   |vtWidget   |
|mnPart |w1000      |w1001      |w1002      |w1003      |w1004      |
|matl   |s1         |s1         |s1         |s1         |s1         |
|spec   |a4b7c3d4   |a4b7c3d4   |a4b7c3d4   |a4b7c3d4   |a4b7c3d4   |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

My first question is it possible to alter the query to do this?

My second question is if I took it a step further, could the query be altered to remove the `matl` and `spec` rows as these respectively contain the same data for each row in their respective columns so that only data which differs is returned:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|cnPart |00001      |00002      |00003      |00004      |00005      |
|qty    |10         |20         |15         |5          |30         |
|desc   |blWidget   |brWidget   |gnWidget   |rdWidget   |vtWidget   |
|mnPart |w1000      |w1001      |w1002      |w1003      |w1004      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

or would I have to do some post-processing to achieve this before opening a report or assigning as a source for a subform?

Thanks

EDIT: to provide further detail in response to comments from @June7

The current querys I have, which is based on responses and a slight modification of my own are as follows:

Query1: qryUNION

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [cnPart],[desc] as DATA,"desc" as CAT from PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [qty], "qty" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [matl],"matl" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT [cnPart], [spec],"spec" FROM PartData)  AS A
WHERE (cnPart IN ('00001','00002','00003','00004','00005'));
```

which provides an output of:

```
|---------------------------|
|cnPart |DATA       |CAT    |
|---------------------------|
|00001  |10         |qty    |
|00001  |a4b7c3d4   |spe    |
|00001  |blWidget   |desc   |
|00001  |s1         |matl   |
|00002  |20         |qty    |
|00002  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00002  |brWidget   |desc   |
|00002  |s1         |matl   |
|00003  |15         |qty    |
|00003  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00003  |gnWidget   |desc   |
|00003  |s1         |matl   |
|00004  |5          |qty    |
|00004  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00004  |rdWidget   |desc   |
|00004  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |30         |qty    |
|00005  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00005  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |vtWidget   |desc   |
|---------------------------|
```

I can see the logic of adding the filter `WHERE ([mnPart] IN ('w1000','w1001','w1002','w1003','w1004'))`, or excluding certain fields but the problem with this is that I just don't know which columns contain the duplicate information until the query is run...  So everytime the query is run, I'd have to manually look to see where duplicates are, edit the query and re-run.

From the `qryUNION` result above, we can see that there are duplicates under the `DATA` column so is is possible remove rows where there are duplications?

So, can we remove these rows as they contain a duplicate value of `S1` under the `DATA` column.

```
|---------------------------|
|cnPart |DATA       |CAT    |
|---------------------------|
|00001  |10         |qty    |
|00001  |a4b7c3d4   |spe    |
|00001  |blWidget   |desc   |
|00001  |s1         |matl   | < REMOVE
|00002  |20         |qty    |
|00002  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00002  |brWidget   |desc   |
|00002  |s1         |matl   | < REMOVE
|00003  |15         |qty    |
|00003  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00003  |gnWidget   |desc   |
|00003  |s1         |matl   | < REMOVE
|00004  |5          |qty    |
|00004  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00004  |rdWidget   |desc   |
|00004  |s1         |matl   | < REMOVE
|00005  |30         |qty    |
|00005  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   |
|00005  |s1         |matl   | < REMOVE
|00005  |vtWidget   |desc   |
|---------------------------|
```

and remove these rows as they contain a duplicate value of `a4b7c3d4` under the `DATA` column.

```
|---------------------------|
|cnPart |DATA       |CAT    |
|---------------------------|
|00001  |10         |qty    |
|00001  |a4b7c3d4   |spe    | < REMOVE
|00001  |blWidget   |desc   |
|00001  |s1         |matl   | 
|00002  |20         |qty    |
|00002  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   | < REMOVE
|00002  |brWidget   |desc   |
|00002  |s1         |matl   |
|00003  |15         |qty    |
|00003  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   | < REMOVE
|00003  |gnWidget   |desc   |
|00003  |s1         |matl   |
|00004  |5          |qty    |
|00004  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   | < REMOVE
|00004  |rdWidget   |desc   |
|00004  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |30         |qty    |
|00005  |a4b7c3d4   |spec   | < REMOVE
|00005  |s1         |matl   |
|00005  |vtWidget   |desc   |
|---------------------------|
```

Can you remove rows like this where duplication occur in a specific column???

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

Query1: qryUNION

```
SELECT cnPart, [desc] AS Data, "desc" AS Cat FROM PartData
UNION SELECT cnPart, [qty], "qty" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT cnPart, mnPart, "mnPart" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT cnPart, mat1, "mat1" FROM PartData
UNION SELECT cnPart, spec, "spec" FROM PartData;
```

Query2:

```
TRANSFORM First(qryUNON.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT qryUNON.Cat
FROM qryUNON
GROUP BY qryUNON.Cat
PIVOT qryUNON.cnPart;
```

Apply the filter criteria in each SELECT of the UNION.

mat1 and spec can be excluded either by not including those SELECT lines in  UNION or by filter in the CROSSTAB.

Resulting dataset is not editable and therefore not very useful on a form.

Alternative to the above queries is export to Excel and use its copy/paste with transpose utility.

Comment: This works brilliantly as it is but I'm struggling with filtering the CROSSTAB to exclude duplicate data.  I cannot exclude from the SELECT statements in the UNION as it is not until I have the data, can I see which are duplicates, so I am left with filtering somehow. How would you filter a CROSSTAB?

Comment: Can have filter in each SELECT: `WHERE ([mnPart] IN ('w1000','w1001','w1002','w1003','w1004'))`.  Exclude mat1 and spec by not including those lines in the UNION.

Comment: Or adding a WHERE in the CROSSTAB: `Cat IN ("qty","desc","mnPart")`. Use Access query designer.